# upgrade to angular 16. 'AbstractControl<any, any> ngfor

Tags: angular

I have some code that look like this

```
this.AccountForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  policyOptions : this.formBuilder.array([])
},{validator: OnePolicyOptionSelected});

 public GetPolicyOptionsCtrls()
 {
   var formCtrl =this.AccountForm.controls;

   var formGrp = <FormGroup>formCtrl.policyOptions;

   return formGrp.controls;
 }
```

and the html for this -

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let pd of GetPolicyOptionsCtrls(); let i=index">
```

Since upgrading to angular 16 this code throws the error

```
error TS2322: Type 'AbstractControl<any, any> | { [key: string]: AbstractControl<any, any>; }' is not assignable to type 'NgIterable<AbstractControl<any, any>>'
```

I'm not really sure what to change.

Thank you.

,msnaxxd adada dadad

Comment: FormGroup.controls is not an area, so you cannot use it inside an ngFor. Try to convert it to an array of abstract controls. `return (formCtrl.policyOptions as FormArray).controls;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `keyvalue` pipe to iterate over objects:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let pair of GetPolicyOptionsCtrls() | keyvalue; let i=index">
```